# What does "they" refer to when Agent Harvey gives his helicopter keys to Davis and Dr Kate?

Tags: rampage

In *Rampage* (2018), while they were about to escape by the medevac helicopter from military, Davis and Dr Kate were interrupted by Agent Harvey. Agent Harvey gives 
his keys to Davis and says:

> Agent Harvey: You know, this ain't no truck stop, amigo. **They** don't 
>   just leave keys under the visor.
>
> Dr Kate: Wait, you're helping us?
>
> Davis: You saved my life. I reckon it's the least I can do.

What does the they refer to here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a case of [generic they](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/They#Generic), where there is no specific target, but rather a larger group of people, in this case people in general, or perhaps the helicopter pilots.

> The pronoun *they* can also be used to refer to unspecified people in some often vaguely defined group, as in *In Japan they drive on the left*. It often refers to the authorities, or to some perceived powerful group, sometimes sinister: *They don't want the public to know the whole truth*.